# Use PhotoSwipe with cli generated Angular 2 project (without System.js)

Tags: angular, systemjs, angular-cli, photoswipe

I want to use PhotoSwipe (http://photoswipe.com/) in my cli generated  Angular 2 project. I tried to use the components from this project https://github.com/wollio/angular2_photoswipe, but it didn't work for me.
I have no idea about the angular-cli.json configuration for building.
(There is no build.js anymore)

In the build.js from Wolli:

```
 map: {
   'typescript': './node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js',
   '@angular': path.resolve('node_modules/@angular'),
   'rxjs': path.resolve('node_modules/rxjs'),
   'photoswipe': './node_modules/photoswipe/dist/photoswipe.js',
   'PhotoSwipeUI_Default': './node_modules/photoswipe/dist/photoswipe-ui-default.js'
  },
```

and later he did some other stuff.

```
var photoswipeImages = [];
photoswipeImages.push({mimeType: 'image/svg+xml', imgName: 'default-skin.png', replaceWith: ""});
photoswipeImages.push({mimeType: 'image/png', imgName: 'default-skin.svg', replaceWith: ""});
photoswipeImages.push({mimeType: 'image/gif', imgName: 'preloader.gif', replaceWith: ""});
var photoswipeDefaultSkin = fs.readFileSync('./node_modules/photoswipe/dist/default-skin/default-skin.css', 'utf-8');
photoswipeImages.forEach(function (img, index, array) {
  var data = fs.readFileSync('./node_modules/photoswipe/dist/default-skin/' + img.imgName, "utf8");
  var base64data = new Buffer(data).toString('base64');
  var regEx = new RegExp(img.imgName, 'gm');
  photoswipeDefaultSkin = photoswipeDefaultSkin.replace(regEx, "data:"+img.mimeType+";base64,"+base64data);
  if (index === array.length - 1) {
    fs.writeFile('./default-skin.css', photoswipeDefaultSkin);
  }
});


builder.config(config);
builder.buildStatic('photoswipe', 'vendor/photoswipe.js', {
  globalName: 'PhotoSwipe'
});
builder.buildStatic('PhotoSwipeUI_Default', 'vendor/photoswipeui.js', {
  globalName: 'PhotoSwipeUI_Default'
});
builder
.bundle('vendor/photoswipe & vendor/photoswipeui & index', path.resolve(__dirname, 'bundles/', pkg.name + '.js'))
.then(function() {
  console.log('Build complete.');
})
.catch(function(err) {
  console.log('Error', err);
```

You can see it on Github. Can anybody help me to use this on my CLI generated project?